# SVN Checkout URL - fresh install

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

I just setup SVN on a server that is running Ubuntu server as a fresh install.  I've got it up and running but am having difficult determining how to connect to it.

I'm trying to do an import using the local IP address: http://IP/RepositoryName but it's saying it can't resolve the IP.  I'm wondering if there's something on the server I need to setup.

I have not modified dav_svn.conf because there is another server here that is running SVN (I'm migrating it to a new server) and it's dav_svn.conf is not modified.  The current working SVN has a subdomain associated with the IP location of the server but doesn't do anything special with the ports as far as I can tell.

I'm getting this error via RapidSVN when I try to import...

```
Error: Error while performing action: OPTIONS of 'http://IP/RepositoryName': could not connect to server (http://IP)
```

Any help would be appreciated

**Update:**
I'm now connecting to the server (didn't realize Ubuntu server came naked without apache, and ssh) and getting the response

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://IP/RepositoryName': 200 OK (http://IP)
```

when I run a checkout.  It sounds to be like there's a disconnect between apache and the SVN service.

Comment: I guess you did copy the error message and replaced your ip address with 'IP' and the repository name with 'RepositoryName', right?

I'm asking just to be sure...

can you provide mor output? Ping the IP, etc?

Comment: Yes I replaced the info.  I can ping the IP just fine from multiple locations within the office.

Comment: Try using the command line client and see what it says.  Also check your firewall settings on the SVN server and what your apache access log files say.

Comment: And you're sure Apache is running and the module is enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> could not connect to server (http://IP

Suggests that it is unable to connect a web server listening (default on port 80) at the IP address.

Using a numeric IP address (e.g. `192.168.77.64`) there is no name "resolving" to be done, so that is not failing.

Can you access the web server itself (e.g. `http://192.168.77.64/`) from the system that you are getting their error via RapidSVN?

If the system does not have a web browser, then `telnet` or `netcat` will do, `telnet IP 80` or `nc -v xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 80`. Hit "enter" or "return" when it connects.

Is http the correct [access method](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.wc.tbl-1) for your SVN server? For example, `svn://IP/RepositoryName` and `svn+ssh://IP/RepositoryName` are other examples of different methods.

I'm assuming you have read and followed the outline at Ubuntu's help on [Subversion](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion).

I hope this helps.

---

Based on your feedback, it sounds like there is a problem with the web server serving to the client portion of SVN repository.

So you can work on debugging this part of the problem. Things to consider are:

- Is the server's [networking correctly configured](https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/serverguide/C/network-configuration.html) and working?

I originally assumed this, but you should verify that it is correctly configured and working if you haven't already. Can you ping the router or gateway, `ping gw.example.com`? Is DNS resolving, `host www.google.com`? Can you ssh to and from the server?

- Is Apache installed and running?

The simplest way to check this is using the [Synaptic Package Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto), and search for the `apache2` package. To see if the web server is running, `ps ax | grep apache2` (note: some systems use the name `httpd` instead of `apache2`).

Is this is the problem, then following the Ubuntu Apache2 Web Server guide should help you get Apache installed and configured enough that you can enable the Subversion access via http.

- Is SVN setup working?

Can you locally (on the server itself) checkout from the repository you set up? `svn co file:///Repository`

Once you know that the repository is setup, then you can edit the Apache config file to [include Subversion](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion#Access_via_WebDAV_protocol_.28http:.2F.2F.29) support.

Good luck, you seem to be doing well so far.

Comment: This is my first time ever setting up a server, so there's a hard learning curve.

I mean, I've been over that stuff sort of.  It's very confusing cause I've read so many different sources I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Apparently I didn't have SSH installed on my server which I've now got up and running.

I am not able to access the IP via a web browser and am installing netcat now...

Comment: when I execute "nc -v IP" it is unable to find the host.... this is after I have installed netcat.... I also still cannot access the IP via a browser.

Comment: I hadn't installed apache because I was told it didn't need it to run.  Is that a completely stupid statement?

I appreciate the encouragement and assistance, I'm knee deep in this and am totally new to it.

It'll be about 2.5 hours before I can mess with the server again.

Comment: It depends whether you really want to be able to access the repository via `http`. If so, then yes you do need Apache. If don't mind using the `svn:` access method, then you can use Subversion's own `svnserve` daemon as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion#Access%20via%20custom%20protocol%20(svn://)

Comment: I'd prefer to be able to access it via HTTPS... so I'm guessing I need apache

Comment: I can in fact SSH to/from the server.  ping/host also correctly provide info about google.com

Apache was not installed, I've used the guide you referred to and now I'm running this command: "svn co http://192.168.15.149/web/ iKeyLess.com --username [MY-USERNAME]" and it's returning "svn: OPTIONS of 'http://192.168.15.149/web': 200 OK (http://192.168.15.149)"  but not performing a checkout.

Comment: Any thoughts on what I need to do now that I'm getting the 200 OK response?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025377/an-svn-error-200-ok-when-checking-out-from-my-online-repo and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239370/tortoise-svn-subversion-update-error  suggests that you may have a typo or the wrong path for repository. Try `svn co http://server.example.com/svn/web iKeyLess.com` where "web" is the project name and "iKeyLess.com" is the module name.

Comment: The `<Location /svn/myproject>` from your apache config should match the URL that you want.

Comment: /web is merely an organizational thing to group the projects within that folder.  /svn/web is setup to forward to svn/web as it should be.